# Solving trigonometric equation using greatest integer function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How to solve the equations $y=\frac {1}{3} [\sin (x) + [ \sin (x)+[\sin (x)]]]$ and $[y+[y]]=2\cos (x) $ ?

P.S. just give hints only.Want to try out myself first.

Comment: I have observed this for a long time, that you aren't showing any attempt in solving most of your questions.

Comment: from the right hand side, notice that $x$ can only be chose such that $2\cos(x)$ is an integer... so by periodicity, of both equalities, not many cases are left... just check them all

Comment: @Roby5 I'll Take Care from the next post...this one I just couldn't think of how to proceed.... (BTW long time..really ? Ok sorry for that )

Comment: @SanchayanDutta , are you not happy with my hint? You only have to check eight cases

Comment: Of course I'm...was trying out that only !

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Using first equation, it can be seen $[y]=-1$,$[y]=0$ or $[y]=1$, and you are just left with three cases, if you consider $[y+[y]]=2\cos{x}$.

Comment: Got it..done... thanks for the help :) @Roby5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good attempt would be to consider two cases.

First take $sin(x) >0$ and then one with $sin(x)<0$. For the first case the G.I.F would itself start reducing {as [$sin(x)] = 0$ and the second case would also follow the same as in the second case $[sin(x)]=-1$. Then just take out the value you get for $y$ and then try to check to for the next equation. Hope it helps.